# How to ng-show using ng-repeat with checklist-model

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

Please help ...

I need to ng-show a particular index which has been taken by Database and showed on html view by ng-repeat and with using checklist-model once that particular index is checked I will show textbox underneath to insert a text in to put it back again in database.

here is my code and the JSON object which has multiple objects taken by DB:

```
mainApp.controller('illnessFollowController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

console.log('illnessFollowController controller initialized')

    $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "resource/getIllnessList",
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(function Success(response) {
      $scope.illnesList = response.data;
      }, function Error(response) {
      console.log("this is a get Error");
      $scope.error;
  });

$scope.user = {
        appliedIlnessIDs: []
}
```

}]);

illnesList array has:

```
[
{id:1;
name:"illness 1";
Active:1;}

{id:2;
name:"illness 2";
Active:1;}

{id:3;
name:"illness 3";
Active:1;}
]
```

these values I want to show them in the view directly

HTML Code:

```
 <div ng-controller="illnessFollowController" dir="rtl">


<label ng-repeat="illness in illnesList">
  {{illness.name}}  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.appliedIlnessIDs" checklist-value="illness.id">
  <br />
</label>

<div ng-show="">


</div>
</div>
```

I want once I put check on ID 3 the ng-show appears

Comment: you need show div when only  checkbox id-3 is checked? or you have divs for each checkbox?

Comment: That's what I want only one div with id 3, I just want to know HOW

Comment: @AbuSlo7 Did my answer below resolve your issue?

Comment: @Carlos13 No it did not, please note that the array is on illnesList not user.appliedIlnessIDs as user.appliedIlnessIDs is to store back what is selected from checklist in an array to store it back to the patient.

Comment: @AbuSlo7 I'm surprised this didn't resolve the issue. When you check the box with id 3, 3 should be added to the user.appliedIlnessIDs array. Therefore if 3 exists in the array it should show your ng-show directive. I'll put together a plnkr later on today to test it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
<div ng-show="user.appliedIlnessIDs.indexOf(3) !== -1">
  <p>This content will show if ID 3 is in user.appliedIlnessIDs array</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and this one worked well ...

```
<span ng-repeat="illness in illnesList">
      <label for="{{illness.id}}">
        {{illness.name}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.id[illness.id]"  id="{{illness.id}}" />
        </label>
        </span>
        <div ng-show="selection.id[3]"><input type="text" ng-model="other"></div>
```

and the javascript side I added this:

```
$scope.selection = {};

    $scope.other ="";
```

Thank you ***SO MUCH*** for your help